# Generating an unordered list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**There is unordered list**, which not works properly in IE6-7, I would like want to **replace it by a jQuery function**.

So, we have:

- simple list with special #id (ul id="")
- some `<li>` tags
- some special tag in `<li>` to show the number of a row (or something else, as you wish).

I need a function which will give an unique number for each row, from the beginning to the end of our unordered list. (ul)

Comment: What type of information are you showing with the list?

Comment: blocks and images with positioning and overflow styles.

Comment: 4 ex - there is an image, which must be placed from the left of a <li> number, and a long text with a big images on the right hand, overflow value is needed, which not works properly in IE unordered lists

Comment: on the left from a <li> number*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul>

$(document).ready(function(){   
    var increment=3;
    var start=8;
    $("ul").children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).prepend('<tag>'+(start+i*increment).toString()+'.</tag>');
    });
});
```

result:

```
* 8. test
* 11. test
* 14. test
* 17. test
* 20. test
* 23. test
* 26. test
```

edit: without increment and shorter:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("ul").children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).prepend('<b>'+(1+i).toString()+'.</b> ');
    });
});
```

Comment: $(this).prepend('<tag>'start+i*increment+'.</tag>');

saw your deleted post on the increment felxibility, don't see this point in this question though ;)

Comment: $(this).prepend('<tag>'start+i*increment+'.</tag>'); - craches and show nothing

Comment: you forgot to add the plus - "'<tag>'+start" :)

Comment: need to start the list from one (1), changed increment and start for = 1, but it starts from 10 - how can I fix that?

Comment: fixed the + tag. 10? I see 1 as it should be.

Comment: It doesnt work when I add some tag inside, "$(this).prepend('<tag>'start+i*increment+'.</tag>')" - this also doesnt work, "$(this).prepend('<tag>'+start+i*increment+'.</tag>')" - this works but starts from 10, needed to start from 1.

Comment: that works now.

can you make it shorter? there is no need for start and increment, the number will go from 1 to XXXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812875/generating-an-unordered-list-with-jquery-80-ready/812890#812890

Comment: but dont remove a ".children()", another way script will be broken if there is a one more list inside <li>

Comment: then green is better, isnt it? :)

Comment: with green is always better ;) shorter version in the edit. cheerz

Comment: I'm waiting, and eating my boots in nervous

Comment: >edit: without increment and shorter:- THIS WORKS!!! YEEEEHA!11 THANKS FOR YOU, JZ! THIS SITE ROCKS!!

Comment: JZ RULES< HE IS THE GOD OF JAVASCRIPT, call me, I will by you a bear

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, no?

```
$(function() {
    $('#the_ul_ID li').each(function(i) { $(this).attr('rel',++i); });
});
```

Comment: KyleFarris, thanks for answer. // this function adds rel="" for a <li> // The numbers need to be visible, how can I do that? // maybe add them in some tag and place inside <li>

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this post [Generating an unordered list with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812875/generating-an-unordered-list-with-jquery/812908#812908)

Is there a way to start count all over again for another list using ul?
With the code above this is what i get!
`<ul>
<li> test
<li> test
<li> test
<ul/>`

Output 
1. test
2. test
3. test

second ul list

`<ul>
<li> test
<li> test
<li> test
<ul/>`

Output
4. test
5. test
6. test

Instead of starting the second ul tag with 1. 2. 3. it continues to count using the first ul 5. 6. 7.

So is it possible to reset the count and star it all over again for another ul tag?

Comment: If you wondering how it is done you can see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765906/start-new-numbered-list-using-jquery