# Start new numbered list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, increment

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var increment=3;
    var start=8;
    $("ul").children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).prepend('<tag>'+(start+i*increment).toString()+'.</tag>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Is there a way to start a new count for another ul list?
With the code above this is what i get!

```
<ul>
<li> test
<li> test
<li> test
<ul/>
```

Output

```
1. test
2. test
3. test
```

second ul list

```
<ul>
<li> test
<li> test
<li> test
<ul/>
```

Output

```
4. test
5. test
6. test
```

Instead of starting the second ul tag with 1. 2. 3. it continues to count using the first ul 5. 6. 7.

So is it possible to reset the count and star it all over again for another ul tag?
If it is possible how?

Comment: Can't you just use an ordered list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordered list:

HTML

```
<ol id="num_list">
  <li>How</li>
  <li>Now</li>
  <li>Brown</li>
  <li>Cow</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
#num_list { list-style-type: decimal; }
```

**EDIT**: if indeed you cannot use an ordered list, then use some JavaScript, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul').each(function() {
     $(this).children().prepend(function(index, html) {
        return '<span>' + (index+1) + '. </span>';
     });
  });
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zZ9z/5/)

Comment: I don't have control over changing the html tags!

Comment: It does the same thing as the code i provided above! It just continues to numbering the other ul list without starting the second ul list from one

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function(i) {
        $(this).prepend('<span>' + (i + 1) + '.</span> ');
    });
});
```

***Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/vSyK6/1/

Comment: For some reason i don't see the numbers!

Answer (score 0):

```
var increment = 1;
$('ul').each(function() {
    var ul = $(this),
        li = ul.find('> li'),
        ol = $('<ol />').attr('start', increment);
    ul.after(ol);
    ol.append(li);
    ul.remove();
    increment += li.length;
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/opuyi/3

This will crap out with nested lists, as they'd (probably) look something like this:

```
1. One
2. Two
    4. Three
3. Four
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this, but then I realized that any CSS styling on the `<ul>` would disappear if this approach were taken.

Comment: @Jacob, if the CSS is also set in stone, then one of the other answers is probably more appropriate. But I'm doubtful that that is the case.